# AngularJS $resource with JSON root node

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm new to AngularJS. How do I deal with server response from `$resource` which includes a root node?

I use `$resource` to fetch a `User` from backend, something like this:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:id', {id:'@id'});
$scope.user = User.get({id: 1});
```

If the response looks something like `{ firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar" }`, I can interact with the `User` in the view with `{{user}}` as usual.

Now, if the response includes a root node, like `{ user: { firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar"`, I need to do `{{user.user}}` to interact with the `User`. I have tried `$scope.user = User.get(1).user` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:id', {id:'@id'});
User.get({id: 1}).$promise.then(function(response){
$scope.user = response.user;
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I'll need to read more about that `$promise`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON `{ firstName: "Foo", lastName: "bar" }` describes object with properties `firstName` and `lastName`

JSON `{ user: { firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar"}}` describes object with property `user` holding object with properties `firstName` and `lastName`

To access `user` directly from second JSON You should do the following :

`User.get({id: 1}).$promise.then(function(response){
  $scope.user = response.user;
});`

In this way You are assigning `user` property of response object to scope's property `user`.